# How to implement the url authentication in java so that only authorized user can access it

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

how to secure my url (eg:-youtube.com), so that only the person who is authorized to access this Url can only decrypt it and get access. And unauthorized people should receive a message "access denied".

```
                   **I need no login page**
```

if i provide the link to some user, then that user can only hit that link and use it, no other user can get access to that link.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Think of using tokens and usermapping with tokens for access urls.

Comment: i have tried it all, i will be thnkful if u give me demo

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share what you tried already? And what do you mean with 'only the user who is authorized can access the url'? How do you distinguish authorized and non-authorized users?

Comment: that's wt i want. how to authenticate a user with url validation process only. without prompting the login page.

Comment: You simply cannot do that. Everyone who has the link will be able to see it. And the others don't have the URL, therefore you don't need to do anything. I mean how will the unauthorized people get to your site in the first place, if they don't have the URL? And what happens if I forward the URL to somebody?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are working with a servlet container, a ServletFilter is probably what you want to use.

Here are some pointers to get you started:

- You need to declare the servlet filter in web.xml to have it apply. (filter and filter-mapping tags)
- You need (of course) an implementation of Filter to make your choice
- If a request is not authorized, either redirect it to an error page, or send an http-not-authorized.

Here is the javadoc for Filter:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

```
public class ExampleFilter extends SomeBaseClass {
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
     if (aRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
       if (!isAuthorizedRequest(aRequest)) {
         ((HttpServletResponse)aResponse).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN); 
         // Maybe write a "you are not allowed" message?
         return;
       }
     }
     chain.doFilter(aRequest, aResponse);
   }
   public boolean isAuthorizedRequest(ServletRequest rq) {
     // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how a `Filter` helps solving the original posters problem?